# Array NullPointerException?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, nullpointerexception

Ok. I don't get why my code is reporting a NullPointerException, but I've been here for quite a while trying to figure it out.

And no, `files` is not `null`.

*Edit: That was a mistake on my part, it was null (I didn't see the order I was running the functions.*

Here is my code:

```
public String[] files;

private void updateRefs(String filepath) {
    try { 
        scr++;
        files[scr] = filepath; //NullPointerException???
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize files somewhere? Is this all your code?

Comment: Because there is no array, only a null reference.

Comment: Well, if you never actually create the array for `files` that would be one possible cause.

Comment: What is src? And you aren't initializing `files` to anything.

Comment: Oh src is the scroll variable so that I can tell where to insert a new item

Comment: I guess I could just do files[files.length + 1] = filepath; ... ;)

Comment: @Tom See edit. No, this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to new it, otherwise it is null:

```
String[] files = new String[10]; //or whatever size you need
```